# height width in percentage css html some weird things

Tags: html, css

I got a weird thing with some css and html code. Following code is works fine when used it in browser chrome,firefox but when use developer tools and insepect with mobile view not understand why but the min-height:100%; is not apply? included a screenshot. So in normal browser works fine any idea it is why? Thanks!

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
* {
  position: relative;
}
a,
body,
footer,
header,
h1,
h2,
html,
img,
li,
p,
section,
span,
sup,
ul {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 210%;
}
body {
  background: red;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 210%;
}
section {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.test {
  float: left;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="test" style="background-image: url('https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-95348.jpg');">test</section>
  <section class="test" style="background-image: url('https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-95348.jpg');">test</section>
  <section class="test" style="background-image: url('https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-95348.jpg');">test</section>
  <section class="test" style="background-image: url('https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-95348.jpg');">test</section>
  <section class="test" style="background-image: url('https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-95348.jpg');">test</section>
</body>
```

The development tools screenshot from Chrome:

[image: screenshoot]

How can make it 100% height on development tools also?

Any idea?

THX!

Comment: i think its because the developer tools takes away from the 100% leaving the window at 71% instead of 100%.

Comment: You didn't close your `head` tag before opening the `body`tag (there's a second opening head tag)

Comment: </head> not fix this things :X and the 100% window in dev tools that same result. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The min-height is being recomputed when you open chrome dev tools inline. If you look closely at the height of the portion of the page that is red, you'll notice that it's height is the same height as your dev tools window. Open dev tools as a separate window and that will fix your issue.

Another solution is to use viewport height instead of percentages. Use `100vh` instead of `100%`

Comment: Thanks! It is do same with 100vh but with this not display background color. It is a little weird why do this but yes the 100vh is a bit better option for this. But still not have idea why it is not make 100vh because its means 100% of viewport height. :_

Answer (score -1):

Your original question contained `</style><head><body>` instead of `</style></head><body>` (notice the added `/` before `head`).

Fixing this will probably solve your issue.

Comment: It is not. :( I will be happy if this will be the problem but it is not :x